# How to get Blocked File Extensions details using SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to get the Blocked File Extensions details using SharePoint Client Object Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is not possible to get the Blocked File Extensions details using SharePoint Client Object Model. If still need to block some file extenstions using SharePoint Client Object Model, then the only option is to maintain a own set of Blocked File Extensions which has same content as SharePoint Default Blocked File Extensions.

Possibly we can use the docextflt.xml available in 14 hives config folder.

Answer (score 5):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
SPWebApplication theApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(myUri);
Collection<string> blockFileTypes = theApp.BlockedFileExtensions;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, is SPWebApplication part of SharePoint Client Object Model? I guess not.

Comment: Sorry. I saw COM and thought of the generic "Component Object Model". The above code is not part of the SP client model. You'll have to query the server, since the server "knows the list", or extend the client model.

Comment: Example for extend: http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/managed-client-object-model-internals-creating-custom-client-om-extensions/